# COM port communication with Virtual PC

Tags: c#, named-pipes, virtual-pc

I am testing an application that uses the COM-Port. The application is running in Virtual PC. I have set up the Virtual PC settings to use the named pipe \.\pipe\mypipe for COM1-Port.

Now I am trying to communicate with this named pipe using C#.

```
using (var pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(@"\\.\pipe\mypipe"))
{
    pipe.WaitForConnection();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(pipe))
    {
       // Do some communication here
    }
}
```

The program is waiting at WaitForConnection() although Virtual PC is running and I am trying to communicate with the COM-Port.

I also tried the following, because I am not sure whether I have to create the named pipe in my program or the named pipe is created by Virtual PC.

```
var p = new NamedPipeClientStream(@"pipe\mypipe");

p.Connect();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up Virtual PC to use a named pipe as a COM port, then it acts as the server (if it were the client then VPC would have to continuously poll for a new server if e.g. your server crashed).

Your second approach is almost on the mark, except that you should use "mypipe" as the pipe's name rather than "pipe\mypipe".

Comment: Thank you! That did it. The communication is still not working though. Maybe you know the answer here, too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907079/com-port-communication-with-virtual-pc-part-2

Comment: @telewin Can you look into this then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715657/named-pipes-in-hyper-v-vm